# Populating a Dockerized PostgreSQL Database through a Dockerized Spring Boot Application

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, docker

I have a Postgres server running inside Docker. Inside this Postgres server, I have a database named 'aa'.

I also have a Docker image of a Spring Boot Application. When this image is executed in Docker, database tables should be created inside database 'aa'.

In order to achieve this, I executed the following steps:

1. Run the Postgres Server inside Docker

   docker run --name PostgresServer --e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=*** -d Postgres

[image]

2. Enter PostgresServer then Create database 'aa'

   sudo docker exec -it PostgresServer psql -U postgres

   CREATE DATABASE AA;

[image]
3. Run the Sprint Boot Docker Image (this is where the problem happens)

```
docker run -v /Users/juancesard.pineda/Desktop/brapi:/home/brapi/properties -d brapicoordinatorselby/brapi-java-server:v2
```

[image]

4. I checked the logs: It says database 'aa' does not exist wherein clearly it exists in the Postgres Server

   org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: database "aa" does not exist

[image]

Some additional info:

- Docker listens at port 8080
- Postgres server listens at port 5432
- My application.properties file looks like this:

  server.port = 8080
  server.servlet.context-path=/Users/juancesard.pineda/Desktop/brapi/application.properties/germplasm

  spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://host.docker.internal:5432/aa
  spring.datasource.username=****
  spring.datasource.password=****

  spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver

  spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
  spring.jpa.show-sql=false
  spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files=sql/crops.sql, sql/lists.sql, sql/locations.sql, sql/people.sql, sql/programs.sql, sql/trials.sql, sql/seasons.sql, sql/studies.sql, sql/breeding_methods.sql, sql/germplasm.sql, sql/attribute_defs.sql, sql/attribute_values.sql, sql/seed_lots.sql, sql/observation_units.sql, sql/crosses.sql, sql/pedigree.sql, sql/events.sql, sql/images.sql, sql/observation_variables.sql, sql/observations.sql, sql/samples.sql, sql/allele_calls.sql, sql/genome_maps.sql, sql/references.sql, sql/vendor.sql

  spring.mvc.dispatch-options-request=true

Am I missing some config in my application.properties file?

Thank you in advance

Comment: keep sql independent of spring boot, you can create docker image extending postgres and execute you sql on startup, otherwise if you are using flyway it will do it for you

Comment: I think the `application.properties` file is usually a text file; you've attached an image to your question instead.  Can you rewrite the question listing the relevant source code and commands you've run as plain text, not screen shots?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your application.properties file. The datasource url is pointing to `host.docker.internal`. This should only be used when connecting something from inside a docker container to something running outside docker on the host machine ([documentation](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/networking/#use-cases-and-workarounds)). You need a different solution because your Spring server and Postgres server are both running inside docker containers.

You need a Docker Network, specifically a bridge network, to connect your different containers. [Docker Bridge Networks](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/)

Try something like this

1. Run this command to create a network in docker called “brapi_net”

   `$> docker network create --driver bridge network_name`
2. Run the postgres container **and link it to the network**. Create your database schema as normal.

   `$> docker run --name PostgresServer --network=network_name --e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=*** -d Postgres`

   `$> sudo docker exec -it PostgresServer psql -U postgres`

   `$> CREATE DATABASE aa;`
3. With a Docker network, container names act as server names. Modify your application.properties to reflect this

   `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://PostgresServer:5432/aa`
4. Run the server container **and link it to the network**.

   `$> docker run -v /Users/juancesard.pineda/Desktop/brapi:/home/brapi/properties --network=network_name -d brapicoordinatorselby/brapi-java-server:v2`